# Deploying container as a CronJob to (Google) Kubernetes Engine - How to stop Pod after completing task

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a container that runs some data fetching from a MySQL database and simply displays the result in console.log(), and want to run this as a cron job in GKE. So far I have the container working on my local machine, and have successfully deployed this to GKE (in terms of there being no errors thrown so far as I can see).

However, the pods that were created were just left as Running instead of stopping after completion of the task. Are the pods supposed to stop automatically after executing all the code, or do they require explicit instruction to stop and if so what is the command to terminate a pod after creation (by the Cron Job)?

I'm reading that there is supposedly some kind of termination grace period of ~30s by default, but after running a minutely-executed cronjob for ~20minutes, all the pods were still running. Not sure if there's a way to terminate the pods from inside the code, otherwise it would be a little silly to have a cronjob generating lots of pods left running idly..My cronjob.yaml below:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: test
spec:
  schedule: "5 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: test
            image: gcr.io/project/test:v1
            # env:
            #   - name: "DELAY"
            #     value: 15
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

Comment: Does your job complete even if use the Jobs object? https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/

Comment: They really should exit once they're done. Can you post your job's configuration yaml?

Comment: @mstorkson I've edited my post with the cronjob.yaml file.

Comment: @Rico I'll try your suggestion soon, but out of curiosity are there any expected differences?

Comment: @jlyh basically, it the job doesn't finish with that option it means that its a problem with your specific app. Your app may not be issuing an `exit` call

Comment: Is that an explicit call? I tried inserting return; but didn't work

Comment: I'll try process.exit() and see if it works, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a process.kill(); line in the code to explicitly end the process after the code has finished executing allowed the pod to automatically stop after execution

Answer (score 1):

A `CronJob` is essentially a cookie cutter for jobs. That is, it knows how to create jobs and execute them at a certain time. Now, that being said, when looking at garbage collection and clean up behaviour of a `CronJob`, we can simply look at what the Kubernetes docs have to say about this topic [in the context of jobs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/#job-termination-and-cleanup):

> When a Job completes, no more Pods are created, but the Pods are not deleted either. Keeping them around allows you to still view the logs of completed pods to check for errors, warnings, or other diagnostic output. The job object also remains after it is completed so that you can view its status. It is up to the user to delete old jobs after noting their status. Delete the job with kubectl (e.g. `kubectl delete jobs/pi` or `kubectl delete -f ./job.yaml`).

Answer (score 0):

A *job* in Kubernetes is intended to run a single instance of a pod and ensure it runs to completion. As another answer specifies, a `CronJob` is a factory for `Job`s which knows how and when to spawn a job according to the specified schedule.

Accordingly, and unlike a service which is intended to run forever, the container(s) in the pod created by the pod must exit upon completion of the job. There is a notable problem with the sidecar pattern which often requires manual pod lifecycle handling; if your main pod requires additional pods to provide logging or database access, you must arrange for these to exit upon completion of the main pod, otherwise they will remain running and k8s will not consider the job complete. In such circumstances, the pod associated with the job will never terminate.

The termination grace period is not applicable here: this timer applies after Kubernetes has requested that your pod terminate (e.g. if you delete it). It specifies the maximum time the pod is afforded to shutdown gracefully before the kubelet will summarily terminate it. If Kubernetes never considers your job to be complete, this phase of the pod lifecycle will not be entered.

Furthermore, old pods are kept around after completion for some time to allow perusal of logs and such. You may see pods listed which are not actively running and so not consuming compute resources on your worker nodes.

---

If your pods are not completing, please provide more information regarding the code they are running so we can assist in determining why the process never exits.